# Why is Lord Jagannath shown as the Buddha Avatara in Puri?

Tags: temple, jagan-natha

[image]On the inner wall of the Puri temple, a panel of the ten avataras are engraved (relief on stone).There we see Matsya, Kurma, Varaha, Nrisimha, Vamana, Parashurama,Rama,Balarama, JAGANNATH and Kalki.

When I enquied about it, the pandas informed me that 'Lord Jagannath IS the Buddha-avatar!

That seemed very surprising to me.How can a deity be an incarnation?

I found an image also on net showing the same.

Can anyone throw light on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Because they don't accept Buddha as an incarnation of Sri Hari.

Comment: No they mentioned Him as the Buddha Avatar. Also, how can a Deity be an incarnation?

Comment: @Pratimaputra is Lord Krishna not an avatar of Vishnu as you have not mentioned about him in the question

Comment: @codeczar no, He is generally accepted as Bhagavan swayam and not counted in the Ten Avatras.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dashavatara according to this link there is a discretion in choice of 8 and 9 avataras some consider krishna and buddha and some consider balarama and jagannath

Comment: @codeczar the dasa-avatara stotra by Jaydev is very famous especially in Bengal and Odissa.Jayadev following Krishna as God Himself does not count Him in the Dasa Avatars. So far as I remember, Garuda Purana also excludes Krishna.

Comment: @codeczar but (krishna, buddha) or (Balaram, jagannath) --this way its not correct.Jagannath is nowhere counted except in Puri so far as I know.